# How to add target=“_blank” to location.href using MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

The following code I need to add `target= "_blank"`:

```
location.href = "@Url.Action("GenericDetailsNew", "Generic"),?GenericID=" + ID;
```

How do I launch the link in a new tab?

**Full code:**

```
'click .detail': function (e, value, row, index) {
                    var ID = row.id
                    location.href = "@Url.Action("GenericDetailsNew", "Generic"),?GenericID=" + ID;
                },
```

Comment: You will need to use `window.open()` instead of `location.href`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes working fine sir thanks